# Angular JS Material Dialog local injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-material

I wanted to write a small app that uses the Material's `$mdDialog` service. But I got an injection error when I try to open the dialog.

The dialog opens with an `ng-click` method, displays a custom HTML file, this HTML file use its own controller, to this controller I inject a custom object `worklogData` which I pass via `locals`.

Here is the Error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?
p0=worklogDataProvider%20%3C-%20worklogData%20%3C-%20WorklogEditController
```

Here is the related controller, which use the html.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('WorklogEdit')
.controller('WorklogEditController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$mdDialog', 'WorklogService', 'worklogData',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog, WorklogService, worklogData) {
```

Here is the dialog angular js code:

```
 $mdDialog.show({
    locals: { worklogData: worklog },
    templateUrl: 'modules/worklog/worklog.edit.html',
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    controller: 'WorklogEditController',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev
}).then(function() {
}, function() {
});
```

The error is trying to point the injected object, which carry the necessary datas, but I can't know when this error coming in, because in the beginning of the development this dialog works correctly. :(

Comment: Well, where is the `worklogData` service defined…?

Comment: The worklogData is not a service, it is just a simple object that carry the inormation.

Comment: Then where is *it* defined?

Comment: As far as I know the worklogData created when the dialog related code runs, The data which encapsulated within it, getting through as a parameter.

http://screencast.com/t/uAonVov4q

Comment: I see now, and I've made the question a little clearer. That *should* indeed work from what I can tell. A more complete example, if possible a ***minimal*** full sample that we could actually run, might clear up the issue…

Answer (score -1):

The worklogData in locals must be sorrounded by '', like so:

```
locals: { 'worklogData': worklog }
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Nothing about `locals` requires this; this is exactly the same as the original as far as Javascript is concerned.